# Deserialization of JSON reponse keeps quotation marks in Strings

Tags: json, serialization, rust, serde, rust-rocket

I am querying a Google API using reqwest:

```
let request_url = format!(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=*\
     &inputtype=textquery\
     &fields=formatted_address,name,place_id,types\
     &locationbias=circle:50@{},{}\
     &key=my-secret-key",
    lat, lng
);

let mut response = reqwest::get(&request_url).expect("pffff");

let gr: GoogleResponse = response.json::<GoogleResponse>().expect("geeez");
```

The `GoogleResponse` struct is defined as

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct DebugLog {
    pub line: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Candidate {
    pub formatted_address: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub place_id: String,
    pub types: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GoogleResponse {
    pub candidates: Vec<Candidate>,
    pub debug_log: DebugLog,
    pub status: String,
}
```

This all compiles and I can make the request, however the result that I am having in the `String` fields contain the original `"`. Is it supposed to be this way?

For instance, when printing one of the formatted addresses I get:

```
"result": "\"Street blabh blahab blahb\"",
```

When I really wanted just

```
"result": "Street blabh blahab blahb",
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Comment: In the future, please provide a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), where you descripe your problem in a minimal way and let us see some code please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll try to provide a simple example here.

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.80
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.33

use serde_json::Value;

const JSON: &str = r#"{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 43
}"#;

fn main() {
    let v: Value = serde_json::from_str(JSON).unwrap();
    println!("{} is {} years old", v["name"], v["age"]);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=dc1e9c43160bf7848cb7a0df990309b2))

will lead to

> "John Doe" is 43 years old

The reason is, that `v["name"]` is not a `String`, but a [`Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.33/serde_json/enum.Value.html) instead (You can check that by adding the line `let a: () = v["name"];` which will result in the error: `expected (), found enum 'serde_json::Value'`).

If you want a `&str`/`String`, you have to convert it first by using [`Value::as_str`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.33/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.as_str).

If you change the `println!` line accordingly:

```
println!("{} is {} years old", v["name"].as_str().unwrap(), v["age"]);
```

it will print out:

> John Doe is 43 years old